# My text classification problem only need an embedding layer but why and how can I solve that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I have a problem with my text classification with tensorflow.
The text was done using the layer TextVectorization and the output_mode="int".
The problem I have, the best test_accuracy I get is with an embedding layer combined with the output layer.
As soon as other layers come between the embedding layer and the output layer, be it Dense, LSTM, CNN layers, the result gets only slightly worse or stays the same.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my Bag of Words:

```
#Tokenizer:
train_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=15000,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=200,
    ngrams=None

train_layer.adapt(X_train)
```

This is my best solution Model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        train_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(15000, 100, input_length=200),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax")
        ])

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Now I can insert more Dense layers or LSTM or Conv1D + GlobalMaxPool1D Layers between the embedding layer and the last dense layer. The result gets slightly worse or stays the same at 0.86 test_accuracy, 0.83 test_precision and 0.8 test_recall in average.
I'am expected that the model with cnn layer(s) or lstm layer(s) are better than the only embedding layer model?

Comment: Not necessarily. It will also depend on your dataset. Are you using some bigger public dataset for experiments?

Comment: what is the issue your trying to solve?  how many hidden layers do you need to capture your feature patterns

Comment: There could be a problem with how you standardize or preprocess the dataset. I have found one similar [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification) which might be helpful. Let us know if the issue still persists.